# Customized ListView with scolling background

Tags: android

EDIT: Solved this by from Java-code adding headers and footers with transparent background to the ListView.

Hi, I'm trying to make a ListView that has a gradient as a background and the content inside a frame. I have some screenshots of what I'm trying to acheive.
The first screenshots shows how I want it too look from start. The list is shown in a box with rounded corners and a green background. This is acheived by adding padding to the LinearLayout surronding the ListView. However, when I add padding on top, the scrolling looks like in the third picture, which is not what I want. The first field with name and phonenumber is a header for the listview.

Any suggestions on how to make the listview behave like this?

[image: Here is the list before the scroll]

[image: This is what I want it too loo like]

[image: This is how it behaves now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Relative layout for solving this problem.

Comment: How do you mean? Should I wrap my ListView in a RelativeLayout?

Comment: YES wrap your hole layout and make it in RelativeLayout

Comment: I have tried that, but the result still looks like in the third picture.

Comment: try to fix the size of ListView it may be possible list view size increase then layout is disturb.